# How to Develop admob (mraid) with the JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, admob, adsense, mraid

I am new for Mraid . I have read all the documents for Mraid which is provided by IAB. It's unclear.

Currently I have created one static HTML Page and custom functions . The custom functions is calling Mraid predefine functions from mraid.js which is already included in html page `<script src="mraid.js"></script>`.

For example:

```
function playVideo(url) // Custom function
{
                mraid.playVideo(url); // Mraid predefine function 
}
```

My questions is:

1. How we will get dynamic images/ anchor link ?
2. The server (Spotxhchange, admob) will return the data in json format / xml format / html page ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question but in general, you can place whatever html or javascript code you would normally include in a web page, into your MRAID tag.

For example, the following tag will display the IAB logo in your ad:

```
<img src="http://www.iab.net/wiki/print/img/iab-logo-0922.png"></img>
```

If this isn't what you meant please clarify further.